# How to include configuration in multiple sinatra application

Tags: ruby, configuration, sinatra

If my Sinatra Application structure is like this. Copied from Sinatra Help

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class LoginScreen  Sinatra::Base
  enable :sessions

  get('/login') { haml :login }

  post('/login') do
    if params[:name] == 'admin' && params[:password] == 'admin'
      session['user_name'] = params[:name]
    else
      redirect '/login'
    end
  end
end

class MyApp  Sinatra::Base
  # middleware will run before filters
  use LoginScreen

  before do
    unless session['user_name']
      halt "Access denied, please login."
    end
  end

  get('/') { "Hello #{session['user_name']}." }
end
```

The question would be if the two applications require the same configuration such as, helpers, registers and asset-pack. How do I make it consistent between the two application without duplicating the code. Could I do something like this?

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class LoginScreen  Sinatra::Base
  include_relative("config_file.rb")
  enable :sessions

  get('/login') { haml :login }

  post('/login') do
    if params[:name] == 'admin' && params[:password] == 'admin'
      session['user_name'] = params[:name]
    else
      redirect '/login'
    end
  end
end

class MyApp  Sinatra::Base
  # middleware will run before filters
  include_relative("config_file.rb")
  use LoginScreen

  before do
    unless session['user_name']
      halt "Access denied, please login."
    end
  end

  get('/') { "Hello #{session['user_name']}." }
end

config_file.rb
helpers Sinatra::Helper1
helpers Sinatra::Helper2
helpers Sinatra::Helper3
register Sinatra1
register Sinatra2
register Sinatra3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using inheritance?

```
class MyBase < Sinatra::Base
  configure do
    helpers Sinatra::Helper1
    register Sinatra1
  end
end

class LoginScreen < MyBase
end

class MyApp < MyBase
  use LoginScreen
end
```

This way configuration gets shared among all applications that descend from `MyBase`.